# How to reorder columns in excel using C# interop

Tags: c#

How to change index of columns in MS excel using interop?

Say I want to move column C to column A position

I wonder how to do this programatically using excel interop

Comment: Did you try swapping data of two columns?

Comment: How to swap data of two columns, (`I am new to excel interop`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This..

// cut column c and insert into A, shifting columns right

```
        Excel.Range copyRange = xlWs.Range["C:C"];
        Excel.Range insertRange = xlWs.Range["A:A"];
        insertRange.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, copyRange.Cut());
```