# How to reorder column at runtime with NPOI or any open source code in export to excel with C#.net

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Need to reorder the Excel runtime programatically with c#. Is there any way in NPOI to shift column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reorder columns in excel using C# interop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121490/how-to-reorder-columns-in-excel-using-c-sharp-interop)

Comment: Thank you for your response but Can you please share the code, want to change the column runtime along with format coating merge or background color settings.